# Data lost when read from pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm learnning Linux programming.Here is my code.I want to write in the child process and read from parent.It seems that some data has lost. What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;

    char buf[1024];

    int link[2];
    pipe(link);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        return -1;
    } else if(pid == 0) { //child process
        //
        char buf_child[256];
        //dup2(link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(link[0]);
        //close(link[1]);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            sprintf(buf_child,"current number is : %d", i);
            write(link[1], buf_child, sizeof(buf_child));
            //sleep(1);
        }
        printf("[child process] now close pipe write end\n");
        close(link[1]);
        printf("child process exit...\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {//parent process
        //
        close(link[1]);
        int nbytes;
        while(1) {
            printf("[parent process] start read...\n");
            nbytes = read(link[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
            if(nbytes == -1) {
                printf("read failed, reason: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                break;
            } else if(nbytes != 0){
                printf("data: %.*s\n", nbytes, buf);
            } else {
                printf("parent process: finish read from pipe\n");
                break;
            }

        }
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[parent process] start read...
data: current number is : 0
[parent process] start read...
data: current number is : 4
[parent process] start read...
data: current number is : 8
[parent process] start read...
[child process] now close pipe write end
child process exit...
parent process: finish read from pipe
```

After Adding sleep statement, all data can be read from parent process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No data is getting lost, your parent process reads up to **1024 bytes at a time**, while the child process writes up to **256 bytes at a time**. Each `read()` done by the parent you will read data for up to 4 iterations of the child loop. Since strings are NUL-terminated, each time you print you will only see the first string because `printf` will stop printing at the first terminator.

You have to either change the parent's buffer size to `256` or use a different mechanism to read the data, e.g. read one byte at a time until you see a NUL `\0` byte. The latter would be more robust. You can also only write the length of the string (returned by `sprintf`).

Also, remember: `read` and `write` do not necessarily read/write *all* the data you request. They can read/write less. Although this is uncommon for a pipe, it can happen. You should always use a loop when issuing raw read/write syscalls.

See also: [Is it necessary to use a while loop when using the read and write system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61590429/3889449)

Answer (score 2):

You receive

```c
"current number is : 0\x00??..??current number is : 1\x00??..??curren..."
```

where `??..??` represents 235 unknown characters.

Then you print up to the first NUL (since one is found before `nbytes` chars are printed).

You need to send only `strlen(child_buf)` characters. With that change, you will receive

```c
"current number is : 0current number is : 1curren..."
```

Pipes transmit a stream of bytes, not a stream of packets. This means the number of reads needed is unrelated to the number writes used. (On that note, `write` needs to be called in a loop just `read`, since it a call to `write` might write fewer than the desired number of characters!)